# Difficulty in forming nine-patch image in photoshop cs6

Tags: photoshop, nine-patch

Hey I am trying to design an interface for android application. Since I am a beginner to Android and Photoshop, I am having a few issues. 
Most important of them is that I try to draw on larger than required canvas ( say, A4 siza; because i am not used to precise drawing) and then duplicate those high resolution (300dpi) layers to a smaller canvas with high resolution to create nine-patch files.
But I am unable to copy those layers; nothing shows up on canvas even if I have layers in the side box.

I have tried it multiple times but same result. Kindly guide me how to properly make a nine-patch image?